# Grouping observations conditional on discrete attribute values

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, cluster-analysis

I have 3 discrete attributes for each observation. If for 2 observations at least 2 of those attributes take the same value, then I want to group them together (it is actually always the case that max. 2 attributes are the same).

My idea was to build a grouping matrix. Each row and each column represents one observation. The intersections of the rows and columns denotes the "similarity" of the two observations which should take the value `TRUE` if at least two of the attribute values are the same and else `FALSE`.

Here is a reproducible example of what I did (`a`, `b`, `c` are the attributes to be compared):

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3), 
                 b = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 4), 
                 c =c("a", "a", "d", "a", "c"))

grouping_matrix <- matrix(nrow = nrow(df), ncol = nrow(df))

for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  for (j in 1:nrow(df)){
    if(sum(df[i, ] == df[j, ]) >= 2) {
      grouping_matrix [i, j] <- TRUE
    } else {
      grouping_matrix [i, j]  <- FALSE  
    }
  }
}

> df
  a b c
1 1 1 a
2 1 2 a
3 2 3 d
4 2 2 a
5 3 4 c
> grouping_matrix 
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
[1,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[2,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[3,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[4,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

This works. However even for a couple of thousend observations it takes forever. 
I am pretty sure there is some much more efficient way e.g. some `data.table` magic. Let me know if the question was not stated clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have performance problems **avoid matrixes**. Anything that requires a distance matrix will require at least O(n²) time, and take forever. And in R, because the R interpreter is *really* slow, avoid any for loop. Rewrite your code in C or Fortran, like all the fast R modules do. Pure R is sloooow.

But your approach has a more general problem. What if a and b should be grouped, b and c should be grouped, but a and c are too different? For example

```
a X Y U
b X Y Z
c V Y Z
```

a and b have X Y in common, b and c have Y and Z in common, but a and c have only Y.

If it is okay to group a and c, then you are looking for the **transitive closure**. A **disjoint set structure** can help accelerating this computation.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion. It is actually not what I wanted. I have to think about it again.

Answer (score 1):

This does the same without the double `for` loop. I'll do a quick performance test to check whether it is considerably faster.

```
grouping_matrix <- do.call(rbind, lapply(1:nrow(df), function(x) rowSums(df[rep(x, nrow(df)),] == df) >= 2))

         1   1.1   1.2   1.3   1.4
[1,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[2,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[3,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[4,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks! But I think it is not really faster. Maybe it is better to first sort the data.frame and merge groups consecutively. This way one could reduce the number of operations since not everything has to be compared with everything.

Comment: Holy crap, you were right when saying this runs forever. Yeah, reducing the amount of operations seems to be key.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, this can solved by *reshaping* and a *self join*. This approach does not compare each row with each other (as in the nested `for` loops or nested `lapply()` approaches) but just looks for matches in column name and value.

```
library(data.table)
mDT <- setDT(df)[, rn := .I][, melt(.SD, id.vars = "rn")]
mDT[mDT, on = .(variable, value), allow = TRUE, nomatch = 0L][
  , .N >= 2L, by = .(rn, i.rn)][
    , dcast(.SD, rn ~ i.rn, fill = FALSE)]
```

> ```
>    rn     1     2     3     4     5
> 1:  1  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
> 2:  2  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
> 3:  3 FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
> 4:  4 FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
> 5:  5 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
> ```

#### Explanation

First, a temporary data.table `mDT` is created by reshaping all columns from wide to long format (after a row id `rn` has been added).

```
mDT
```

> ```
>     rn variable value
>  1:  1        a     1
>  2:  2        a     1
>  3:  3        a     2
>  4:  4        a     2
>  5:  5        a     3
>  6:  1        b     1
>  7:  2        b     2
>  8:  3        b     3
>  9:  4        b     2
> 10:  5        b     4
> 11:  1        c     a
> 12:  2        c     a
> 13:  3        c     d
> 14:  4        c     a
> 15:  5        c     c
> ```

Then, `mDT` is joined with itself on the names of columns and the values:

```
mDT[mDT, on = .(variable, value), allow = TRUE, nomatch = 0L]
```

> ```
>     rn variable value i.rn
>  1:  1        a     1    1
>  2:  2        a     1    1
>  3:  1        a     1    2
>  4:  2        a     1    2
>  5:  3        a     2    3
>  6:  4        a     2    3
>  7:  3        a     2    4
>  8:  4        a     2    4
>  9:  5        a     3    5
> 10:  1        b     1    1
> 11:  2        b     2    2
> 12:  4        b     2    2
> 13:  3        b     3    3
> 14:  2        b     2    4
> 15:  4        b     2    4
> 16:  5        b     4    5
> 17:  1        c     a    1
> 18:  2        c     a    1
> 19:  4        c     a    1
> 20:  1        c     a    2
> 21:  2        c     a    2
> 22:  4        c     a    2
> 23:  3        c     d    3
> 24:  1        c     a    4
> 25:  2        c     a    4
> 26:  4        c     a    4
> 27:  5        c     c    5
>     rn variable value i.rn
> ```

The parameter `nomatch = 0L` is an attempt to reduce the number of resulting rows as the OP has reported a problem with his production dataset.

Now the number of matches are counted for each combination of `rn` and `i.rn` and it is checked if the number is greater 1:

```
mDT[mDT, on = .(variable, value), allow = TRUE][
  , .N >= 2L, by = .(rn, i.rn)]
```

> ```
>     rn i.rn    V1
>  1:  1    1  TRUE
>  2:  2    1  TRUE
>  3:  1    2  TRUE
>  4:  2    2  TRUE
>  5:  3    3  TRUE
>  6:  4    3 FALSE
>  7:  3    4 FALSE
>  8:  4    4  TRUE
>  9:  5    5  TRUE
> 10:  4    2  TRUE
> 11:  2    4  TRUE
> 12:  4    1 FALSE
> 13:  1    4 FALSE
> ```

Finally, this result is reshaped to the matrix-like structure as requested.

Comment: Thanks for that answer. If I try it on my real data I get for the line `mDT[mDT, on = .(variable, value), allow = FALSE]` the error:
`Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian || notjoin || !anyDuplicated(f__,  : 
  Join results in more than 2^31 rows (internal vecseq reached physical limit). Very likely misspecified join. Check for duplicate key values in i each of which join to the same group in x over and over again. If that's ok, try by=.EACHI to run j for each group to avoid the large allocation. `

Comment: As I read it, the resulting table is too large. I tried to add `by = .EACHI` but could not get it working. Any idea?

Comment: How large is your dataframe (rows x columns)? Are there any other columns besides the 3 attributes? If so, they need to be included in the `id.vars` param.

Comment: Please, try to add `nomatch = 0L`. If this fails we can try 64-bit integers (rather desperate assumption) or filling only the upper triangle of the matrix (should reduce number of rows by nearly 50%).

Comment: Thanks for your efforts to help! But I will discard this approach since it does not provide the solution I am lookin for  (See Anony-Mousse's anwer).

Comment: @Alex You are welcome. It is an interesting problem. I am looking forward to seeing your follow-up question on SO. Perhaps, you can ping me then?

Comment: I will do that ;) But I think it is more about methodology than programming.